# Can't do reverse DNS lookup on Android

Tags: android

I have an Android device connected to Wifi network with an IP address. I did NS lookup on my Linux computer of this IP address and verified that there is a corresponding hostname for that IP address.

I have a piece of Java code, which when run on my Windows PC does reverse DNS lookup fine (returns a hostname):

```java
String dnSuffix;
String ipAddress = "10.228.59.217";
InetAddress inetAddr;
try {
    //inetAddr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    inetAddr = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
    //System.out.println("inetAddr = " + inetAddr);
    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "inetAddr = " + inetAddr);
    if (inetAddr != null) {
        dnSuffix = inetAddr.getHostName();
        //System.out.println("dnSuffix is " + dnSuffix);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG,"dnSuffix is " + dnSuffix); 
    }
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    //System.out.println("Error getting DN suffix: " + e.getMessage());
    Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Error getting DN suffix: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

`dnSuffix` is the hostname as expected on Windows.

But on Android, it returns an IP address instead of a hostname, which indicates that it failed.

I have all the permissions that I would think I need for this in my app:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" ></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I found this documentation:

> getCanonicalHostName
>
> public String getCanonicalHostName()
>
> Gets the fully qualified domain name for this IP address. Best effort
>   method, meaning we may not be able to return the FQDN depending on the
>   underlying system configuration. If there is a security manager, this
>   method first calls its checkConnect method with the hostname and -1 as
>   its arguments to see if the calling code is allowed to know the
>   hostname for this IP address, i.e., to connect to the host. If the
>   operation is not allowed, it will return the textual representation of
>   the IP address.
>
> Returns:
>
> the fully qualified domain name for this IP address, or if the
>   operation is not allowed by the security check, the textual
>   representation of the IP address.
>
> Since:
>
> 1.4
>
> See Also:
>
> SecurityManager.checkConnect(java.lang.String, int)

I also found someone having similar problem:

[getCanonicalHostName returns an IP address](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-security-discuss/nVUoTz_zQBI/ZL4tzSbHbqoJ)

But no resolution.

Can anyone provide any help at all?

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure it can works at all, following 2.3 sources (shortened)

```
inetAddr = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
getByName(numeric) -> getAllByName/Impl(numeric) -> lookupHostByName(numeric)
return bytesToInetAddresses(getaddrinfo(host), host)[0]
```

host is the numeric string, then calling getHostName() on the resulting object will return host (the ip)