# Mulesoft - How to get the remote host (caller) details?

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4

One of our experience API is being called by our multiple customer systems. We want to log the origin of the call with the caller **host (domain) and IP address** so that we know what was the origin of the request.

How do I capture the **origin/host** details?

I found the `attributes.remoteAddress` gives the **IP details** only.

Answer (score 0):

Internet communication is actually implemented using IP addresses. When you use a DNS name or a host name it is used as an alias for the IP address. You could try to use a reverse DNS lookup to find the DNS alias that matches an IP but that is not always possible, depending on how the DNS is configured. Mule HTTP Connector doesn't implement a reverse lookup feature. You would need to implement it yourself in Java and call it from your flow. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68338888/721855 for an example on how to implement it in Java code, and the [Java Module documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/java-module/1.2/) to use the code from a Mule application. But remember that it will depend on the DNS configuration if it is possible to reverse lookup any IP.